# Shifting Array Elements in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

> Write a program that uses an array of size eight (8) and then prompts
> the user to input eight integers for the array. The program should do
> the following:
>
> 1. Print the numbers in the output given in the sample Input/Output.
> 2. The user is prompted to enter an integer value k, the program will then shift the array elements k positions to the right, while the last
>    K elements are moved to the beginning of the array.  For example: if
>    we have an array [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8], shifting 2 positions to the right
>    should give the array [7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6].

I did this question but I got the output (if assumed number of shift = 3)
[1 0 3 1 2 3 4 5] which is wrong, the output should be [6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5]

This is my code, what is the mistake?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int arrays[8];
    int k;


    cout<<"Enter Values for a Arrays of size 8"<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        cin>>arrays[i];
    }


    cout<<"You Entered Numbers are: [ ";
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        cout<<arrays[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<" ]\n";

    cout<<"Enter the Number of Shift: ";
    cin>>k;

    for(int i=8; i>0; i--)
    {

        arrays[i]=arrays[i-k];
    }

    //The Output
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        cout<<arrays[i]<<" ";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For an array of X elements, what is the top element index? What indexes are your "shifting" (I would call it *rotation*) loop using? I also recommend you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Oh and once you've finished with your exercise and feel like you learned something, then read about [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate).

Comment: No no no, that's not what I mean. If you have an array of 8 elements, then the top index is 7, right? Now at what index do your loop start at? What is the first index you will use?

Comment: i will start looping with the index 7 (element number 8) which is in my example is 6

Comment: No you don't. The initialization is `int i = 8`. That's your starting index. And it is out of bounds, leading to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: you can Run the code and then you will know what i was mean

Comment: Hi @AlaaKM , problem is in your for loop condition. (i - k) will be negative for k > 1. And you need to swap elements at arrays[i] and arrays[i - k]. Your loop condition should be for (int i = 7; (i - k) >= 0; i --)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in

```
for(int i=8; i>0; i--)
{

    arrays[i]=arrays[i-k];
}
```

First of all when `i<3` you get a negative index. You can solve this using the `%` operator which returns the reminder.

Secondly you are overwriting the values that still must be copied. For example suppose the shifting is 3: at the first iteration you copy the fifth element inside the eighth. But then you should also copy the eighth inside the third.

One simple solution is to declare a new array and do the following:

```
int shifted[8];
...
for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    shifted[i] = arrays[(i-k)%8] 
}
```

Consider also using C++ vectors.